# How to normalise a column of a dataframe, ignoring None values in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to normalize a column of a dataframe, that also contains None values, how do I do it using a lambda function?

I tried using :
df['Log GDP per capita'] = df['Log GDP per capita'].apply(lambda x:((x-b)/(a-b)))

where my a is maximum value and b is minimum value

```
    a = df['Log GDP per capita'].max()
    b = df['Log GDP per capita'].min()

    df['Log GDP per capita'] = df['Log GDP per capita'].apply(lambda x:((x-b)/(a-b)))
```

I get this error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need apply

```
df['Log GDP per capita'] = (df['Log GDP per capita']-b)/(a-b)
```

Also you can call the [`sklearn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
caler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.transform(df['Log GDP per capita'])
```